# Android NDK crashes at low memory conditions (Crashlytics reporting)

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, crashlytics

I see some crashes (99.5%+ crash-free sessions) from my application in Crashlytics control panel related to NDK. Those crashes (mostly SIGSEGV SEGV_MAPERR, but sometimes SIGBUS BUS_ADRALN too) appear in random places. For all of them Crashlytics reported low status of free RAM (2-4%, only in one crash report I saw 15% of free RAM). I use libc++ (static linking, because I have just one dynamic library in my app) + the latest NDK (v16). Code was written in C++14 and compiled with following flags -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -fstack-protector. The same code used in iOS app works perfectly fine, so for me it looks like Android doesn't kill apps in background fast enough to release their memory, so in this case my app has OOM problems, however it's interesting why those issues don't occur on Java side too (maybe VM reserve much more additional free RAM). Did you saw similar problems? Maybe you know how to deal with them?

BTW. Sometimes stack provided by Crashlytics reports is really bad (only for crashes in native code, Java is fine), I even got 2 crashes called '??? - unknown'. I uploaded symbols by Crashlytics task for gradle. Do you know how to solve that?

Cheers,

Comment: In regards to the Crashlytics reports with "???", if you write into support@fabric.io with the link to your crash, we can dig into the logs and see what's going on.

Comment: I'll do that, thanks.